# npm prune removes dependency module

Tags: npm, package.json

In my `package.json` file I have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper": "^0.7.3",
    "@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper-annotations": "^0.7.3",
    "@my-company/common": "file:../common",
    ...
  }
```

`@my-company/common` specifies a local module which is installed by yarn.

However, when I run `npm prune`, this module is pruned.
I thought that including it in the `package.json` `dependencies` object would stop it from being pruned? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across this, I discovered that running `npm ls` showed that there was an error with the common module.

Installing with NPM instead of Yarn fixed the issue.

Installing with Yarn did create the package within `node_modules`, however there was obviously an error somewhere which I couldn't uncover.